# RJDBC Parallel query in R

Tags: sql, r, rjdbc

I have a code header that looks something like this in SQL Developer:

```
    ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL QUERY
    SELECT /*+PARALLEL(dfam 32)*/
    distinct dfam.a,dfam.b from d_f_a_market dfam;
```

I am trying to use parallel query in R using RJDBC. I have a code that looks like this:

```
queryResults <- dbGetQuery(conn, "
SELECT /* +PARALLEL(dfam 32)*/
distinct dfam.a,dfam.b from d_f_a_market dfam;")
```

But I can't see any time improvement on using the hint. The query takes the same amount of time without sql hint. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you review the output of `EXPLAIN PLAN` for the hinted query? Does it behave faster outside of JDBC?

Comment: Yes it is significantly faster in SQL developer once I use hints.